# Azure; Permission error accessing Key Vault from Java Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am trying to access a Key Vault to retrieve a Secret from Azure Key Vault from a Java application.
For my code I followed the directions at the following link, and I also see the same
code on other links:  http://www.stratogator.com/2017/10/20/how-to-access-secrets-in-azure-key-vault-using-java/

The code requires 4 things: a ClientID and ClientKey, and also a Key Vault URL and the Secret Name.

To get the ClientID and ClientKey I Registered an Application in 
Azure Active Directory.  From here I got the Application ID to use as the ClientID.
I also created a Key to use as the ClientKey.  I copied both of these values carefully.
Under Permissions, I also granted this application access to Azure Key Vault. It shows the following checked:
  "Have full access to the Azure Key Vault service".

I created my Key Vault and also the Secret.  I added some Access control (IAM) so that my AD Application would
be able to access the Key Vault.  I was not sure what to add so I went overboard thinking this would cover it.
I granted the AD application the following Roles: Owner, Contributor, Key Vault Contributor, and Reader.

However when I try to retrieve a Secret using the Vault URL and Secret Name I get the following exception:
com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.models.KeyVaultErrorException: 
Status code 403, {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Access denied","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}

Any idea on what I am doing wrong, or permissions I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question after I posted my question.  It has the solution:
[Azure key vault: access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied?rq=1)