# Azure Key Vault working in locally but getting 403 forbidden error in azure cloud

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure. I want to use Azure `KeyVault` to store secrets like passwords. I have successfully created All steps which mentioned in Microsoft website. And also able to get secrets (passwords from `KeyVault`) in our local environment by using `Springboot` application.properties .

But getting `403 Access denied` error when I tried the same in Azure Cloud. It is not generated in local tomcat server. Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

Expected password, but getting `403`.

Comment: application.properties -> azure.keyvault.client-id=XXX
azure.keyvault.client-key=XXX
azure.keyvault.uri=https://XXX/

Comment: Does your VM/Resource has access to KeyVault? If not you have to look into " managed service identity"

Comment: I do not have "managed service identity" , but without this my spring boot application is working fine in locally. And getting secrets as well in local environment.

Comment: the reason it may be working because you may have signed into your Azure Account locally and your IDE lets you bring the data since you are already authenticated.

Comment: I tried the same with local tomcat standalone server without using IDE and it is working on that but not working on Azure cloud. So Is managed Identity must for KeyVault?

Comment: @surendratomar Which document did you refer to?

Comment: @Caiyi Document link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: @surendratomar Did Azure Cloud refer to azure web app?

Comment: @surendratomar I deployed my app to azure web app and can get the secret successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to

1. [Enable system-assigned managed identity on an existing VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm#enable-system-assigned-managed-identity-on-an-existing-vm)
2. [Grant your VM access to a Secret stored in a Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-nonaad#grant-your-vm-access-to-a-secret-stored-in-a-key-vault)
3. [Use Springboot key vault dependencies to get the secret.](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample#add-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell run these commands to verify if key vault has right access permissions.

- Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName  check what objectIds you see
- Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ObjectId  check if your service's service principle (from AAD) is listed there.

you can also check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied) which i think may help you.