# How to fix "KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'" when downloading a storage blob

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault

I'm getting a KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'when i tried to download a storage blob (DownloadToStream).

I tried creating another rsa key. But the same error occured.
When i use a secret. Everthing is working fine.
I checked the keyvault access policies.
The User Account has full permissions.
The App has get and list permission for keys and secrets.

Here is the complete code.
It's based on this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault).

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace KeyVaultTest
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         // This is standard code to interact with Blob Storage
         StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountName"],
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountKey"]);
         CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
         CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
         CloudBlobContainer contain = client.GetContainerReference("test123");
         contain.CreateIfNotExists();

         // The Resolver object is used to interact with Key Vault for Azure Storage
         // This is where the GetToken method from above is used
         KeyVaultKeyResolver cloudResolver = new KeyVaultKeyResolver(GetToken);

         // Retrieve the key that you created previously
         // The IKey that is returned here is an RsaKey
         // Remember that we used the names contosokeyvault and testrsakey1
         var rsa = cloudResolver.ResolveKeyAsync("https://mykeystorage.vault.azure.net/keys/testkey9000/", CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


         // Now you simply use the RSA key to encrypt by setting it in the BlobEncryptionPolicy. 
         BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(rsa, null);
         BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

         // Reference a block blob
         CloudBlockBlob blob = contain.GetBlockBlobReference("MyFile.txt");

         // Upload using the UploadFromStream method
         using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\MyFile.txt"))
            blob.UploadFromStream(stream, stream.Length, null, options, null);


         // In this case we will not pass a key and only pass the resolver because 
         //  this policy will only be used for downloading / decrypting
         policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, cloudResolver);
         options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy };

         using (var np = File.Open(@"C:\temp\MyFileDecrypted.txt", FileMode.Create))
            blob.DownloadToStream(np, null, options, null);
      }

      private async static Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
      {
         var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
         ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"],
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"]);
         AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

         if (result == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

         return result.AccessToken;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please check if you have configured Azure key vault access policy for your AD application? For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied?rq=1

Comment: Ok. I am glad to know your issue has resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access key vault resource, you need to configure access policy for your AD application and let it have enough permissions to access key vault resource. For more details, please refer to [Azure key vault: access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied?rq=1).