# Accessing an Azure vault key from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to encrypt fields using AlwaysEncrypt in SSMS with a key stored in Azure vault.
I've created a vault and a key given it all the permissions (so I don't miss anything, I know I shouldn't give it all of the permissions eventually, just what it needs).

Following through the encryption wizard, I can log into my Azure account and everything proceeds nicely until the final commit, when it fails with the following message.

```
Dec 31 2019 10:59:10 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Generate new column master key CMK_Auto2 in Azure Key Vault MyVault' -- Status: 'Started' -- Details: 'Task 'Generate new column master key CMK_Auto2 in Azure Key Vault MyVault' started ....'.

Dec 31 2019 10:59:10 [Informational] TaskUpdates: Message:Task: 'Generate new column master key CMK_Auto2 in Azure Key Vault MyVault' -- Status: 'Failed' -- Details: 'Task failed due to following error: Access denied. Caller was not found on any access policy.
Caller: appid=aGUID;numgroups=0;iss=https://sts.windows.net/anotherGUID/
Vault: MyVault;location=ukwest'.

Dec 31 2019 10:59:10 [Informational] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Generate new column master key CMK_Auto2 in Azure Key Vault MyVault' stopped..

Dec 31 2019 10:59:10 [Error] WorkitemExecution: Message:Work item 'Generate new column master key CMK_Auto2 in Azure Key Vault MyVault' did not complete. Details: Access denied. Caller was not found on any access policy.
Caller: appid=aGUID;numgroups=0;iss=https://sts.windows.net/anotherGUID/
Vault: MyVault;location=ukwest'.
```

Any ideas which permissions I need to add to somewhere or what I'm pointing incorrectly to?

Comment: Did you create an app registration and grant the permissions to that app?  Check this out...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied

Comment: Regarding the issue, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault?tabs=azure-powershell.

Comment: Does the SQL server database have to be in Azure?   My database is on my PC and I'm trying to connect from there.

Comment: @Glyn did you ever figure out question? I'm trying to connect my local database to keyvault.

Comment: @zachattack No sorry, it got pushed to the back of the queue. I'll post an answer when I get round to figuring it out ;)