# Azure Cloud Service Role's instance have access denied errors: "caller was not found on any access policy"

Tags: azure

My Azure Cloud Service (classic) has one role with two instances that are receiving access denied errors when trying to access a key vault because a caller that they are using was "not found on any access policy". I don't know who the caller is, but it did provide me with the caller's appid, oid, and iss. How do I find out who the caller is?

I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied)... do I use one of the accepted answer's procedures to grant the caller access to the key vault?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the caller by appid when adding a Service Principal to an access policy. I then followed [the question that I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025598/azure-key-vault-access-denied) and it all worked.